# What is the return of this?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
__CGSizeEqualToSize(CGSize size1, CGSize size2)
{
    return size1.width == size2.width && size1.height == size2.height;
}
```

What is the return of this?

Comment: Why is there no return type on this function?

Comment: @rmaddy the question is what it will return,not how the function should look

Comment: @sken3r.MI Having a contradiction between the definition and implementation of a function does not help at all for its understanding

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo this is why i added an Answer ))

Comment: It returns the boolean value of if the two sizes are the same.

Answer (score 2):

From Core Graphics Framework Reference

**Swift**

```
 /* Return true if `size1' and `size2' are the same, false otherwise. */

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func CGSizeEqualToSize(size1: CGSize, _ size2: CGSize) -> Bool
```

I think it is self explanatory

Comment: Except the code in the question is in C/Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: Again, the question is what the code returns, not how or in witch language ...and as you can see there is a pretty little comment `/* Return true if size1 and size2 are the same, false otherwise. */` this is a native function, that you dont need to invent yourself available since iOS2.0.

Answer (score 0):

if size1's width equals size2'width AND size1's height equals size2's height, it'll return true.
Otherwise, it'll return false.

And, there's no type in your function, you must specify it (boolean)